# conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result - GCC , C

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, warnings

In my project I have turned on treat warnings as errors and compiling using the `-pedantic` and `-ansi` tags. I am using GCC compiler. In this project I have to use a third party source code which has got lot of warnings. Since I treat warnings as errors, I am having a tough time in fixing their code.

Most of the warnings are about invalid conversion from `int` to `size_t` or viceversa. In some cases, I won't be able to make both the variables same type, I mean I won't be able to change something to `size_t`. In such cases I am doing an explicit cast. Something like,

```
size_t a = (size_t) atoi(val);
```

I am wondering is this the correct approach? Is there any problem in doing cast like this?

If these warnings are minor, can I suppress it only on their files? How do I do the same on MSVC?

Comment: you certainly can run other gcc commandlines on different files.

My approach would indeed be not fixing their code (because incompatibility in later version dot dot dot). You should perhaps send in bugreports, if they care.

Answer (score 7):

Edit:

Casting is the only approach if you want to shut up the compiler per instance in a portable way. It is fine as long as you know what you're doing, e.g. that you can ensure the result of `atoi` will never be negative.

In GCC, you can turn off all sign conversion warnings with the `-Wno-sign-conversion` flag. There is also `-Wno-sign-compare` (for stuff like `2u > 1`) but it won't be relevant unless you use `-Wextra`.

You could also use the [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) like

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-conversion"
```

In MSVC, there are several warnings relevant to signed/unsigned mismatch, e.g.:

- Level 4:

  - [C4389](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx7x617k.aspx), [C4245](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9s7thk1.aspx), [C4365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173683.aspx)
- Level 3:

  - [C4018](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2.aspx) (`2u > 1`)
- Level 2:

  - [C4267](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kck0s93.aspx) (`size_t` → `int`)

To disable a warning in MSVC, you could add a [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) e.g.

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4267)
```

or add a `/wd4267` flag in the compiler options.

---

Perhaps you should use [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) instead of `atoi`.

```
size_t a = strtoul(val, NULL, 0);
```

(There is no warning *only if* `size_t` is as large as `unsigned long`. On most platforms, this is true, but it is not guaranteed.)

The advantage is you could perform error checking with this function, e.g.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char val[256];
    fgets(val, 256, stdin);
    char* endptr;
    size_t a = strtoul(val, &endptr, 0);
    if (val == endptr) {
        printf("Not a number\n");
    } else {
        printf("The value is %zu\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `atoi` is shown just as an example. My questions was about the casting and suppressing specific warnings on specific files.

Comment: +1 for the diagnostic pragmas, it's exactly what I need for my Pro*C code where I have annoying warnings generated by the preprocessor that I can not fix.

Comment: Why eradicate `atoi`? It's likely to outperform `strtoul` by several times since it doesn't have to check for overflow. If you don't care what return value you get when someone puts in a ridiculously overlarge number, `atoi` seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the OpenOffice wiki on the best practices for error-free code: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Writing_warning-free_code

They suggest static casts for these conversions, and then supply a pragma to disable warnings for a particular section of code.

Comment: Thanks. I am using C not C++. `static_cast` is not available.

Comment: In that case, use your good judgement and explicit-cast away :)

Answer (score -2):

I personally consider this kind of warning idiotic and would turn it off, but the fact that you're asking about it suggests that you might be sufficiently unfamiliar with conversions between integer types and the differences in signed and unsigned behavior that the warning could be useful to you.

Back on the other hand again, I really despise [explicit] casts. The suggestion to use `strtoul` instead of `atoi` is probably a very good one. I see you commented that `atoi` was only an example, but the same principle applies in general: use functions that return the type you want rather than forcing a different type into the type you want. If the function is one you wrote yourself rather than a library function, this may just mean fixing your functions to return `size_t` for sizes rather than `int`.